Experiencing an error while trying to compile an exe with the help of pyaudio
Been trying to run pysilon on github to test out its capabilities on my machine and come across this error:
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      WARNING:root:Warning: VCPKG_PATH envrionment variable not set.
      INFO:root:running bdist_wheel
      INFO:root:running build
      INFO:root:running build_py
      INFO:root:creating build
      INFO:root:creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      INFO:root:creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\pyaudio
      INFO:root:copying src\pyaudio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\pyaudio
      INFO:root:running build_ext
      INFO:root:building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
      INFO:root:creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37
      INFO:root:creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release
      INFO:root:creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\src
      INFO:root:creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\src\pyaudio
      INFO:root:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 "-Ic:\users\andrew & mindy chipp\downloads\pysilon-malware-3.7-fix1\pysilon-malware-3.7-fix1\pysilon\include" "-IC:\Users\Andrew & Mindy Chipp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Users\Andrew & Mindy Chipp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/pyaudio/device_api.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\src/pyaudio/device_api.obj /MT
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      device_api.c
      C:\Users\Andrew & Mindy Chipp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
      C:\Users\Andrew & Mindy Chipp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): note: 'MS_WIN64' previously declared on the command line
      src/pyaudio/device_api.c(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

When trying to compile the exe. Anyone know a solution or any suggestions towards fixing it? I've reinstalled visual studio, python, tried installing pyaudio which spits the same exact error out. I expected an exe to be built

I'd suggest creating a Linux virtual machine and trying this there. I think doing this in Windows is probably upsetting it.

Or you could try WSL in Windows, which is basically Ubuntu.
